# Symfony 3 merge form - collection printing error (printing only label)

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using symfony 3.0.5.
I have form with field of type "collection". And when i'm printing collection form I only get label.

[image]

My code:
UserType.php

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstname')
        ->add('lastname')
        ->add('username')
        ->add('password')
        ->add('address')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
    ));
}
}
```

ClientType.php

```
class ClientType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('money')
        ->add('user',CollectionType::class,array(
            'entry_type' => UserType::class
        ))
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Client'
    ));
}
```

Client.php

```
class Client
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="client")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $user;
...//set,get:money,id,...
}
```

User.php

```
class User
{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Client", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $client;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->client = new ArrayCollection();
}
....//set get: name,id,lastname...
}
```

ClientController.php

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $client = new Client();
    $user = new User();

    $form = $this->createForm(ClientType::class,$client)
            ->add('submit',ButtonType::class);
....
}
```

create.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h2 class="page-header">Client</h2>
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You need to add the user to the client so that the user collection is not empty. Another option would be to leave the collection empty but add the "add user" button/form using the prototype property (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype).

Comment: I just added ClientType::class to UserType::class and it's now working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form.money) }}
{{ form_row(form.user.firstname) }}
{{ form_row(form.user.lastname) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

[Edit]

As you use collectionType (Is a mistake?), you need to loop on user, try :

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form.money) }}
{% for user in form.user %}
    {{ form_row(user.firstname) }}
    {{ form_row(user.lastname) }}
{% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

But I think your entity are misconfigured, maybe take look on this :

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
// ...

$builder->add('user', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
));
```

Comment: Still not working.,Now i get: Method "lastname" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in client\create.html.twig at line 7

Comment: Are your sure you set User in Client entity ?

Comment: Also A think make me perplex, why hold user in a collection as your are on the owning side of manyToOne association. Use `EntityType::class` should does the trick.

Comment: I set EntityType and new code twig and now i get this: https://i.imgsafe.org/083133a.png

Comment: What do you want ? complete form or only select list of user ?

Comment: User in client is not a list since it lives in manyToOne relation side. don't use collectionType, but entityType, please provide code you write, difficult without...

Comment: client class - http://pastebin.com/mSCS9Mp2   user class - http://pastebin.com/PnC6DZvg

Comment: It's strange you initialize client as array, but set as client line 210, if you use this careful, secondly I don't understand your bdd schema who own who ? Is you client just inherit user ? Because what you write is : a client own many user, a user is owned by one client !

Comment: Can you please provide your type files ?

Comment: have to try to use `form_widget(form.user)` with entityType

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tB6R9TMK - ClientType http://pastebin.com/8391Q0rt - UserType. About schema: i changed this for test because i wanted try "inverse" forms (i have got the same problem before).

Comment: It's not working with entity type. Still same problem.

Comment: I think about oneToOne entity and try inverse on (entity which not have referenced column in his table)...

Comment: Which oneToOne? http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html W

Comment: Look [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional).

Comment: Ok, new form: https://i.imgsafe.org/6391d6e.png  client class - http://pastebin.com/NKAMqLjb user class - http://pastebin.com/qhcs2ia7 clienttype class - http://pastebin.com/5fW7vxAv usertype class - http://pastebin.com/5rJSvpUn When i try use {{ form_widget(form.client) }} i get this: https://i.imgsafe.org/be5caee.png

Comment: Try  to add `'property'=>'money'` to client under UserType
.